# On the $PSL(2, p)$, $p$ a Mersenne prime

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We know $|PSL(2,p)|=p(p+1)(p-1)/2$. Let $p$ be Mersenne prime (that is $p+1=2^{n}$) and $r$ be prime divisor of $(p-1)/2$.

My question: What is the number of Sylow $r$-subgroups of $PSL(2,p)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=\operatorname{PSL}(2,q)$ for *q* an odd prime power. If *r* is an odd prime not dividing *q* but dividing $|G|$, then *r* divides exactly one of $\{q+1,q-1\}$ and a Sylow *r*-subgroup of *G* is cyclic with normalizer dihedral of order $q-\epsilon$ ($\epsilon = \pm1$). In particular, the number of Sylow *r*-subgroups is $q(q+\epsilon)/2$.

The normalizer is a at least this big because it obviously normalizes the subgroup, and it is no bigger, since it is a maximal subgroup.

This does not require *q* to be a Mersenne prime, or even prime (just odd), and does not require *r* divide $q-1$ (though in your case this means $\epsilon=1$).

Comment: I was about to start typing an answer based on a calculation showing that that the normalizer of a non-trivial subgroup of the subgroup of the diagonal matrices (such as these subgroups of order $\mid (p-1)$) consists of the monomial matrices, and thus is dihedral of order $2(p-1)/2$. +1 and thanks for saving me the trouble :-)

Comment: No problem.  I thought this was explicitly done in Gorenstein's textbook, but I don't see it.  I've definitely seen it clearly presented in a  standard textbook somewhere (and would like to add this to the answer).  The only reference I know of right now that has it is the paper that describes the Sylow p-subgroups of PSL(n,q) (where we only need the very easy case for r > n, r not dividing q).

Comment: @JackSchmidt: thank you so much.